# include push notification (parse php sdk)

Tags: php, android, cakephp, parse-platform, push-notification

i want to use push notification in my site.I am using parse PHP sdk, I have included the php sdk file in my root directory.This is the line of code which I wrote

```
    require "parse-php-sdk-master/autoload.php";        
    require "parse-php-sdk-master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php";
    ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');
    $data = array("alert" => "Hi!");

    ParsePush::send(array(
      "channels" => ["PHPFans"],
      "data" => $data
    ));
```

But Iam receiving this error **Fatal error: Class 'ParseClient' not found**

Any help appreciated....

Comment: files is not included properly. Problem in this line :  require "parse-php-sdk-master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php"; use the static absolute path and try..

Answer (score 0):

you should add after the require files:

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParsePush;

Cheers.